# Why does my program keep looping?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to sort a 2d array in increasing order and stores them in a one dimensional array (from low to high).

```
16 22 99 4 18
-258 4 101 5 98
105 6 15 2 45
33 88 72 16 3
```

but what i have is keep looping and i don't know why

```
 int main()                  
 {                             
     const int SKIP=-999999;
     const int SIZE=20;
     const int ROWS=4;
     const int COLS=5;         
     int unsorted_array[ROWS][COLS]= {(16,22,99,41,18),
                                      (-258,4,101,5,98),
                                      (105,6,15,2,45),
                                      (33,88,72,16,3)};   
     int s_index=0;
     int min_value,rowMin,rowCol,row,col,colMin;
     int sorted[SIZE];

     cout <<"Array Sorted"<<endl
         <<"___________"<<endl<<endl;


 while (s_index < SIZE)
 {
     rowMin=0;
     rowCol=0;
     min_value = unsorted_array[0][0];
     row=0;
     while (row < ROWS)
     {
         col=0;
         while (col < COLS)
         {
             if (unsorted_array[row][col] < min_value)
             {
                 min_value = unsorted_array[row][col];
                 rowMin = row;
                 colMin = col;
             } 
             ;
             col = col + 1;
         }
         row = row + 1;  
     }
     sorted[s_index] = min_value; 

     while (sorted[s_index] >= 0)
     {
         cout<<" "<<sorted[s_index];
     }
     unsorted_array[rowMin][colMin]=SKIP; 
     s_index=s_index+1; 
}
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I suggest replacing `col=0; while (col<COLS) { ... col=col+1 }` with `for (col=0; col < COLS; ++col) { ... }`.

Comment: Please format your code properly. I do hope your actual indentation doesn't look like that exhibited in your question.

Comment: Run your program with a debugger attached.  Step through the program until the actual state of the program does not match the expected state.  Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: You should be using braces for the sets in the second dimension, not parentheses. `int arr [2][2] = {{0,1},{2,3}};`

Comment: Will @Jay please let us know the progress about this. Is the problem solved? Can an answer be accepted?

Answer (score 7):

If `sorted[s_index] >= 0` is true once, this will be an infinite loop:

```
 while (sorted[s_index]>=0)
 {
     cout<<" "<<sorted[s_index];
 }
```

s_index never gets changed within that loop.

Answer (score 3):

Here is A problem. The while condition never changes inside the loop, so the loop will never terminate if the predicate is true

```
while (sorted[s_index]>=0){
  cout<<" "<<sorted[s_index];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if the predicate is true, this is an obvious infinite loop:

```
while (sorted[s_index]>=0)
   {
     cout<<" "<<sorted[s_index];

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by the others your cout loop is endless. Better use:

```
     for (int i=0; i < SIZE ;i++){
         cout<<" "<<sorted[i];
     }
     cout << endl;
```

Comment: or increase the `s_index` variable inside the while loop, but yeah, that would work!